# Regex in python (123/4)

Tags: python, regex, csv

I have the following string :

```
line = '5320411,  996/7     W/O ABC ANO-20'
```

where I want to add a comma after I encounter a number of the form 123/4.
My approach is to use Regular expression which I'm fairly new to. I tried the following :

```
re.sub('^(\S+)\s+\[0-9]{3}/[0-9]{1}', ',', line)
```

First I am checking for one or more spaces at the beginning followed by three digit number followed by a slash and then another number. However I can't seem to get how to we put comma after the occurence of this pattern.

The expected output should look like :

```
line = '5320411,  996/7 ,    W/O ABC ANO-20'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**`re.sub`**

```
re.sub(r'\b(\d{3}\/\d)\b', r'\1,', line)

# Output
'5320411,  996/7,     W/O ABC ANO-20'
```

Regex explanation (demo [**here**](https://regex101.com/r/HW9Ovo/3)):

```
\b                  # Matches a word boundary
(                   # Start of matching group 1
  \d{3}             # Matches 3 digits
  \/                # Matches /
  \d                # Matches 1 digit
)                   # End of matching group 1
\b                  # Matches a word boundary
```

The key here is that we don't want to replace our pattern with a comma, we want to replace our pattern with our pattern *plus* a comma, and we can do this by capturing our pattern in matching group one, and replacing with matching group one, with a comma added in at the end, or:  `\1,`

Comment: Just one little thing. If after the slash I have two digits instead of one, would I use re.sub(r'\b(\d{3}\/\d{1 | 2]})\b', r'\1,', line) to check for both one and two digits ?

Comment: Correct, `\b(\d{3}\/\d{1,2})\b` would accept either 1 or 2 digits.

Answer (score 2):

You use a positive lookbehind:

```
import re
line = '5320411,  996/7     W/O ABC ANO-20'
new_line = re.sub('(?<=\d{3}/\d{1})\s', ' ,', line)
```

Output:

```
'5320411,  996/7 ,    W/O ABC ANO-20'
```